# Converse of Schur complement positive definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}A_{11}&A_{12}\\A_{21}&A_{22}\end{bmatrix} \text{be hermitian}$$

Given: $A_{11} $ and $A_{22}-A_{21}A_{11}^{-1}A_{12}$ are both positive definite, then show that $A$ is positive definite.

Since $A$ is hermitian $A_{11}^*=A_{11}, \; A_{22}^*=A_{22}, \;A_{12}^*=A_{21}\;\; ->>(1)$

Let $$B=\begin{bmatrix}A_{11}&0\\0&A_{22}-A_{21}A_{11}^{-1}A_{12}\end{bmatrix}$$

Let $U^*=\begin{bmatrix}I&0\\-A_{21}A_{11}^{-1}&I\end{bmatrix}$

Then, using $(1)$, please verify that

$U^*AU=B$

How can I make use of this to prove that $A$ is also positive definite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first check that $S$ has hermitian symmetry :

$$S^*=A_{22}^*-(A_{21}A_{11}^{-1}A_{12})^*=A_{22}-(A_{12}^*(A_{11}^{-1})^*A_{21}^*)=$$
$$=A_{22}-(A_{21}(\underbrace{A_{11}^{*}}_{A_{11}})^{-1}A_{12})=S.\tag{1}$$

(please note that we have used the fact that the inverse of a transpose-conjugate is the transpose-conj. of the inverse).

$B$ is positive definite because its eigenvalues are the union of

- those of $A_{11}$ which are real positive, because  $A_{11}$ is symmetric definite positive with hermitian symmetry, and
- those of $S:=A_{22}-A_{21}A_{11}^{-1}A_{12}$, all of them being as well $>0$ for the same reason ($S$ is assumed positive definite and we just verified in (1) that it has hermitian symmetry).

Besides, a consequence of conjugation relationship $U^*AU=B$ is that $A$ and $B$ have the same (positive !) eigenvalues.

Therefore, $A$, having all its eigenvalues $>0$ is (symmetric) positive definite.

Comment: don't I need $B$ to be hermitian (and so along with positive eigenvalues, which will show it is positive definite)?
I think $B$ is hermitian using $(1)$. Is that correct?

Comment: In fact, what was missing in my proof is the fact that S has a (hermitian) symmetry :  I have modified my answer in this direction. Moreover, I had assumed that $A_{11}$ is a number instead of a full fleshed matrix : I have fixed the corresponding argumentation.

Comment: Just a small remark, but $U$ is not in general unitary. So, while it is true that $A$ is positive definite, it is not true in general that $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues. A possible workaround is to write $B$ as $V^*V$ where $V$ has the same size as $B$ and is non-singular, and then deduce that $A = (VU^{-1})^*(VU^{-1})$. Then, because $V$ and $U$ are both non-singular, it follows that $A$ is positive definite.

Comment: @Malkoun Thanks for your comment : I must take the time to fully understand it.

Comment: An $n \times n$ matrix $H$ is hermitian positive semidefinite iff it can be written as $H = V^*V$, where $V$ is some complex $m \times n$ matrix (where $m$ is not necessarily equal to $n$). So any hermitian positive semidefinite matrix is the Gram matrix for some vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ in a vector space $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: On the other hand, an $n \times n$ matrix $H$ is hermitian positive definite iff it can be written as $H = V^* V$, where $V$ is $n \times n$ and non-singular. So any such matrix is the Gram matrix of $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Here is an argument to convince you. Take each block $A_{ij}$ to be $1 \times 1$. If $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues (which I claim is not true in general), then since $A_{11}$ (which is a scalar here) is an eigenvalue of $B$, it would follow that $A_{11}$ is always an eigenvalue of $A$, which is not true in general.